# Upload Azure Blob from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

So we can [upload a blob onto Azure from Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/06/10/windows-azure-storage-browser-in-the-visual-studio-server-explorer.aspx) IDE using the server explorer.

And it always uploads Block type blobs. It seems to be the default setting.

Is there any direct way or work around to upload [Page type blobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee691964.aspx)?
Did not find any options to do so.

Basically we are trying to avoid using another tool/plugin to do so, if VS can do it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can upload page blobs using Visual Studio's Server Explorer. So your choices are:

- Use a 3rd party solution: Make sure the solution supports sparse upload i.e. upload only the occupied bytes.
- You can also use `AzCopy` tool which is built by storage team. More information about this tool can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/12/03/azcopy-uploading-downloading-files-for-windows-azure-blobs.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/09/07/azcopy-transfer-data-with-re-startable-mode-and-sas-token.aspx.
- Use storage client library/REST API to write your own code: You may find this blog post from storage team useful regarding this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/04/11/using-windows-azure-page-blobs-and-how-to-efficiently-upload-and-download-page-blobs.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

I posted here previously saying that I had issues with the few third-party Azure Blob Storage applications that I have found and used; the best I could find until recently was the Azure Storage Explorer from the CodePlex website, but I've since been shown an alternative that has changed my mind.

[Cerebrata](http://www.cerebrata.com) (now owned by Red Gate) make a pay-for application called Azure Management Studio, which as the name suggests allows almost full control of your Azure account from a desktop application.  One small part of this application provides the ability to manage the Blob storage contents.

In addition, Cerebrata also make a free application called Azure Explorer (http://www.cerebrata.com/labs/azure-explorer) which focuses entirely on Blob storage management.

Through use of both apps I've mentioned above, I felt as though Azure Blob storage is brought closer to the desktop, as you're able to move files (drag/drop/etc) between your local PC and storage much easier than I've found before.